# One line NDK crashlogs on android

Tags: android, android-ndk, crashlytics, crashlytics-android, google-fabric

We have application which depends on ndk library packaged as aar. Also this app builds it's own NDK code using cmake.

We upload symbols using `crashlyticsUploadSymbols<Flavor>` task. And when I check `build/fabric/<flavor>/release/csyms` there is csym files for both libraries and all our supported architectures.

Everything seems ok, but native crashes symbolicated [like this](https://fabric.io/entrepreneur/android/apps/com.bodunov.galileo/issues/564369d8f5d3a7f76b7e60ac). Lots info about system lines and no info about contents of libglmapview which is most interesting part of every crash.

What is our next steps? How to find why it won't unwind native stack trace?

Comment: On API levels lower than 16, the two unwind methods we use (libcorkscrew and libunwind) are not present, so we default to our own simple unwinder.Currently, the simple unwinder is only able to capture the top-most frame in a crash. If you notice this for a crash report coming from a device between API 16 and 22, the crash could be happening in a very inlined context.To verify if you’re seeing full crash info on your dashboard, open the device logcat containing the tombstone of the native crash.

Comment: Thanks @ToddBurner. Is there a way to make sure that everything is uploaded correctly for current build or turn on some logging from fabric tools to see that everything generated and uploaded without issues?