# did crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease actually work?

Tags: android-ndk, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

as followup on *[One line NDK crashlogs on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474262/one-line-ndk-crashlogs-on-android#comment74096299_43474262)*: Is there a way to make sure that the symbols have been uploaded correctly for current build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. There is not an explicit way to check if the symbols have been uploaded for a specific build.

Comment: Could  this question be converted into a feature request?